# Build specific BlackBerry project in Eclipse workspace

Tags: eclipse, blackberry

I have a workspace in Eclipse containing two BlackBerry projects. I started the workspace with the first project and later added the second project. Now I wanted to build and run the second project, but Eclipse keeps starting the first project in the BlackBerry simulator. When I close the first project and try to run the second one again, I get the error message "Launching DebugServer has encountered a problem. Resource FIRST PROJECT is not open." I think I have to configure Eclipse/BlackBerry simulator to build and run the second project an some place, but I can't find out where to do it. I hope someone can help me, as I also fail to move the second project into another workspace for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. The projects that are to be built and run can be configured in the menu "BlackBerry -> Build Configurations -> Edit". For every mode ("private", "debug" and "release") I had to uncheck the first project and check the second one.