# How to remove installed Java programs on the simulator?

Tags: blackberry, java-me, simulator

There are lots of java apps on my simulator menu screen which I have been coding and testing? Now I want to remove some of them to clean my simulator a bit. How do I remove them?

Comment: C:\Users\{windows_user}\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\Program Files (x86)\Research In Motion\BlackBerry Smartphone Simulators 7.0.0\7.0.0.236 (9900)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quote from [Reset and clean the blackberry simulator](http://theblackberrydeveloper.blogspot.com/2006/06/reset-and-clean-blackberry-simulator.html):

> Are you sick of having a million icons on your BlackBerry simulator for every HelloWorld and demo project you have every tested? Try this to remove old programs from the simulator and start with a clean ribbon. From the command line browser to your rim jde directory, switch to the simulator sub directory and run clean.bat. This program takes longer than you would expect (about 30 seconds or so on my 3 ghz machine).

**UPDATE**
Also delete all [app name].cod|cso|debug|jar files from simulator folder
Also make sure projects you don't want on simulator are not active and are not in build configuration.

See [Build specific BlackBerry project in Eclipse workspace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1216789/build-specific-blackberry-project-in-eclipse-workspace)

Answer (score 3):

Run **clean.bat** file from the "simulator" folder located on your installation path

```
C:\Program Files\Research In Motion\BlackBerry JDE 4.5.0\simulator
```

Or if you are using BB plugin for eclipse then it must be under foll.path

```
C:\Eclipse\plugins\net.rim.eide.componentpack4.5.0_4.5.0.16\components\simulator
```

Comment: Thanks. I did that. It does reset my simulator to the default settings but doesn't delete the applications in it.

Answer (score 0):

Please following these steps to remove Java Programs from Emulator,

Go to Project Menu, --> Select BlackBerry Option  and then select Clean Simulator.

The Shortcut key is <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>C</kbd>