# Why doesn't my Blackberry app update when I change the code?

Tags: java, eclipse, blackberry, blackberry-simulator

I'm having trouble getting my application to change once it's on the blackberry simulator. I run my program once, it works fine, then I change a few lines of code, rerun the app and nothing has changed.

It seems like once the app gets installed on the simulator that I can't change it. I'm using Eclipse to develop my app. I'm just clicking debug to run my app.

So why isn't my application changing on the simulator? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reset the state of the simulator using the `clean.bat` script that is included in the simulator directory.  For example:

```
C:\Program Files\Research In Motion\BlackBerry JDE 4.6.0\simulator\clean.bat
```

[*See also.*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1648800/how-to-remove-installed-java-programs-on-the-simulator)

Answer (score 1):

You can also edit the .bat file that runs the simulator, adding the `/clear-flash` tag will ensure that each time it loads the flash memory will be cleared.