# JVM: could not open

Tags: java, eclipse, blackberry-simulator

> Error - JVM - BlackBerry 9800
>   Simulator
>   --------------------------------------- JVM: could not open
>   C:\Users\Bayron.Tellez\Downloads\eclipse-java-helios-win32\eclipse\plugins\net.rim.ejde.componentpack6.0.0_6.0.0.29\components\simulator\Java\net_rim_bis_lib.cod

My friend installed Eclipse with the Blackberry simulator. I'm assuming it was a portable installation because at no point we were prompted to install.

Now, he zipped it up and copied it to my machine when running I receive that error above. Obviously it's because it's trying to look for something on my friends directory. How can I change it to my path?

My path is:

```
C:\Eclipse\eclipse\plugins\net.rim.ejde.componentpack6.0.0_6.0.0.29\components\simulator\Java\net_rim_bis_lib.cod
```

Where do I change this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would suggest not running eclipse from a copy of someone else's installation. This will probably contain lots of installation-specific files which are unlikely to match your machine.

Why not install it yourself, then install the Blackberry Java Developer plugin? It's available at http://na.blackberry.com/eng/developers/javaappdev/devtools.jsp

Answer (score 2):

You can change the early installed paths of all `.cod` files from `xml.manifest`

```
[Eclipse Installed Path]\plugins\net.rim.ejde.componentpack7.1.0\components\simulator\[BlackBerry simulator version].xml.manifest
```

Eg:

```
C:\Program Files\Eclipse\plugins\net.rim.ejde.componentpack6.0.0_6.0.0.30\components\simulator\9800.xml.manifest
```

Then remove the `[BlackBerry simulator version].xml.manifest.bin` file.

Now it should be work.

Comment: Please format your answer properly. Check [editing-help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for editing the answer.

Comment: I was looking for the file which has the path hardcoded and this was it. Worked for me. Thanks much.

Answer (score 1):

You may also want to check file Settings.rc,
found in the folder
PATH\plugins\net.rim.ejde.componentpack4.6.1_4.6.1.49\components\bin

first you have a path to your eclipse installation, and then corresponding Simulator you are trying to run.

hope this helps,

Answer (score 1):

1. Use notepad++ to replace all occurrances of old directory into new directory in the eclipse directory.
2. Start the eclipse, and click clean simulator button.

That should be all.

Answer (score 1):

Though it is not advisable to run a copy of eclipse, there is a very simple way for one to solve such a problem: it is by running the **clean.bat** file that is in the simulator folder of the specific component pack version folder. The path to that file would look like this: `PATH\plugins\net.rim.ejde.componentpack[BlackBerry version]\components\simulator\clean.bat`

I think that would do.
Still, installing a new version is the best option.

Answer (score 0):

It will be better you install it yourself frsh rather than copying it from friends machine.

But you can give it a try.

Goto your eclipse\plugins\net.rim.ejde.componentpack6.0.0_6.0.0.29 directory and check do on of these files contain this path:

1. plugin.properties
2. plugin.xml
3. META-INF/eclipse.inf
4. .options

Or else you could grep for problem path in your plugin directory and replace same with updated path.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurse cause your simulator have previously loadded application. Removing them solve your problem.

[How to remove installed Java programs on the simulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1648800/how-to-remove-installed-java-programs-on-the-simulator)

Quote from Reset and clean the blackberry simulator:

Are you sick of having a million icons on your BlackBerry simulator for every HelloWorld and demo project you have every tested? Try this to remove old programs from the simulator and start with a clean ribbon. From the command line browser to your rim jde directory, switch to the simulator sub directory and run clean.bat. This program takes longer than you would expect (about 30 seconds or so on my 3 ghz machine).

UPDATE
Also delete all [app name].cod|cso|debug|jar files from simulator folder Also make sure projects you don't want on simulator are not active and are not in build configuration.